# Linux event after creating /dev/ttyUSB*

Tags: linux, usb, linux-device-driver, modem

I have been using a 3G dongle on cubieboard for internet connection. I have installed usb_modeswitch which basically switched dongle from USB storage mode to USB modem mode. I verified that the switching automatically happens after boot (usb_modeswitch is working fine). After switching takes place, system adds /dev/ttyUSB* dev names for modem. After this happens, I need to run model script to dial and connect to internet. In order to automate the process, I wanted to know if there is any event trigger for creation of /dev/ttyUSB* so that after that, I can automatically run dial script?

Answer (score 0):

A general approach is to use [udev](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/kernel/hotplug/udev/udev.html) to listen for events and then to react according to your own logic.